# asp net dropdownlist with javascript onscroll

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have this page with a bunch of users that each has dropdown lists of items, so when the page has enough users to get big enough to scroll down, the dropdown lists follows you when for example taking the last users even after scrolling back up.

I tried to resolve this with javascript:

```
//function here is called onscroll when dropdown is read

            window.onscroll = function () { onscroll() };
            function onscroll() {
                if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
                    document.getElementById("pHolder").className = "test"; //pHolder is my dropdownlist
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("pHolder").className = "";
                }
            }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're describing or what you're asking.  Can you provide a more complete example and a demonstration of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if im not mistaken what you are trying to to is that you have multiple dropdown lists and need to apply something to them

so you cannot use the id selector id should be used for only one single element and

```
 document.getElementById("pHolder")
```

so you need to select your dropdown list in terms of class or node name by using jquery like

```
$(".SomeClass")
```

or with pure js like

```
 document.getElementByClassName("SomeClass")//Loop And Apply your Code
```